# Scrollbar is hard to activate and quite touchy

Tags: scrollbar

I've just installed 22.04.1 on a secondhand Lenovo in excellent condition.

In Firefox and LibreOffice, when I position the cursor over the almost invisible bar at the side, it enlarges, indicating it knows my cursor is over it. Once the bar is active and enlarged, about half the time scrollbar will not scroll no matter how I position the cursor. I have tried over and over, carefully, in the middle of the bar and have tried different positions like toward the edge to see if that is the "sweet spot".

My technical knowledge extends only to type things into the terminal that I have found described here. I have not tried any kind of fix except to change the settings relevant to the scrollbar and touchpad. I turned natural scrolling off/on, two finger and edge scrolling switched back and forth.

I am not a fan of the very narrow bar, as it requires extra focus/attention to use it, even when it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the scrollbars permanently visible you can disable the GNOME Overlay Scrolling with:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface overlay-scrolling false`

Probably need to log out and back in for it to be effective.